# Do iOS provide an api to make UITextField auto-filled when incoming sms

Tags: ios, swift

I want autofill in my `UITextField` whenever I receive `sms` in my mobile. So is there any possibility ?

Comment: No. Not possible.

Comment: Though this user experience is very good，I also think third-party applications should have no jurisdiction，welcome to share if you find that implementation method

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use the same in one of my projects but found that it is not supported in iOS.